# Automatically Delete Elasticsearch Index After Reindexing Completed

Tags: elasticsearch

I wanna delete an index as soon as reindexing is completed. Doubt weather if I do reindex and delete in a single call will the index be deleted before reindexing is completed and as a result reindexing fails with a data loss.

In order to save space, I will reindex the main index with a reduced number of fields after 7 days. Once the reindex operation is completed the main index must be deleted. Problem is reindexing takes over one hour to complete as I have 100 million records per day.

Comment: Whats the use case? Why are indexing if you have to finally delete it? Please elaborate more on it and what have you tried for the scenario.

Comment: In order to save space, I will reindex the with a reduced number of fields after 7 days. once the reindex operation is completed the main index must be deleted. problem is reindexing takes over one hour to complete as I have 100 million records per day

Comment: What method are you using to reindex? You can use scroll api to do it faster.

Comment: For me, the number of docs remains same even in new index with lesser number of fields and reduce in size. So, I passively query for number of docs in an index with a backoff and once I am sure re-indexing is complete, I delete my old index. This strategy can be implemented if you could accurately estimate the number of expected docs in your new index.

Comment: Why not use a TTL (time to live) if you only need a 7 days backlogs?